# How can I convert two lists from JSON into a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

Here is my JSON:

`{'date': [1498017600, 1498018500, 1498019400], 'plotPoints': [80.767918, 221.597006, 405.602822]}`

How can I convert this into a Pandas DataFrame as such?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>date</th>
    <th>plotPoints</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1498017600</td>
    <td>80.767918</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1498018500</td>
    <td>221.597006</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1498019400</td>
    <td>405.602822</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the one you are looking for?

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_l)
```

Produce this

```
         date  plotPoints
0  1498017600   80.767918
1  1498018500  221.597006
2  1498019400  405.602822
```